# Java & PHP runtime communication

Tags: java, php, watchdog

I'm writing a watchdog-style program in Java - that is, it will be running constantly.
I want to be able to somehow send input and receive a response using PHP.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Just to clarify, the Java and PHP are running on the same machine.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=java+catch+signal&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 I went through the results and seems it is there. Or I gave a very simple but crud solution below.

Comment: Sorry, what solution? Simple sounds nice :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really simple solution,not as simple as the "file solution" by Itay), but more light-weight than HTTP or XML-RPC would be using a plain socket-based solution, as simple as illustrated [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

That would fit nicely for your "String back and forth" protocol.

Answer (score 0):

There are a million ways to do this: one comparatively easy way is using a networked RPC system such as [XML-RPC](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/). You can quite cleanly call from PHP and receive the responses back.

Comment: Well, that does do what I need. However, considering I only need to pass a string and receive a string - is there any other simpler way? That just seems like overkill.

Comment: Well, you're right: it is overkill. However I'd still go with a higher level solution like XML-RPC: it is more heavyweight but it really simplifies the integration as it is just a couple of setup calls and then standard function calls on either side and its much more robust to changes if you decide you need to ever do more than just ship a string. If you already have networking support baked in you COULD just do a network connection and pass strings: not as robust to future changes, but has worked well for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

very crud and not the most efficient
A socket like way:

1. Create file A with permissions to both the Java process and php process.
2. Java writes to the file, only when it is empty (or concatenate)
3. PHP reads the file and deletes it.
4. Do the same but the other way around for the PHP to send input to Java.

Again, this is crud and as you can see in the search result above, there are ready made solutions.

Comment: Actually, that sounds fine. Indeed, this was my initial idea, but I thought for sure there had to be a better way. I'm not looking for a complicated solution :)

Comment: I would go with the signal thingy, should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this by running the Java program in a servlet container (Jetty or Tomcat would do just fine) and use HTTP request/response between the PHP and Java. The Servlet will effectively provide an HTTP interface to your Java program. On the PHP side you can use cURL, `file`, or even `fopen` to perform GET requests, or cURL to perform POSTs and retrieve responses.

The data format you use for transactions is up to you, JSON seems like an easy choice, there's built-in support in PHP and excellent libraries for Java.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something with all those giant libraries floating around, but what about using a socket and communicating over TCP? Can't get much simpler for transmitting simple data like strings and should be fairly performant.